# How to unpack the contents of a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, eval, unpack, compression

You know how those packed js files look like, right?

```
 eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){ ... } ('obfuscated-string'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

It just so happens to be that i have to tweak some large legacy code that looks like that and I want to find a way to turn this into a more readable version.

If that's not possible, can i at least get rid of the eval?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can with online unpackers: try one of these, find one that suits you:

- [Dean Edwards Unpacker](http://dean.edwards.name/unpacker/)
- [JSUnpack](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/)

Answer (score 14):

JS Beautifier will both reformat and unpack:

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: I used this to unpack one complex javascript. It cleanly unpacked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [unpacker](http://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker#unpacker).

Answer (score 0):

```
eval(function(W,H,A,K){function z(i){return(i< 62?'':z(this['parseInt'](i/62)))+((i=i%62)>35?String.fromCharCode(i+29):i.toString(36))}for(var i=0;i<W.length;i++)A[z(i)]=W[i];function d(w){return A[w]?A[w]:w;};return H.replace(/\b\w+\b/g,d);}('alert|Testing|packed'.split('|'),'0("1 0 2");',{}));
```

What I do is change eval to document.getElementByID('test').value= and then make sure I have a textarea (no DOM parsing, multilines) wuth id

```js
test.value=(function(W,H,A,K){function z(i){return(i< 62?'':z(this['parseInt'](i/62)))+((i=i%62)>35?String.fromCharCode(i+29):i.toString(36))}for(var i=0;i<W.length;i++)A[z(i)]=W[i];function d(w){return A[w]?A[w]:w;};return H.replace(/\b\w+\b/g,d);}('alert|Testing|packed'.split('|'),'0("1 0 2");',{}));
```

```html
<textarea id=test rows=9 cals=77></textarea>
```

='test'

Comment: http://www.scriptcompress.com/unpack.htm is a online tool I made for unpacking, also http://www.scriptcompress.com/decoder.htm will try to decode it in the DOM, through JSOn parser and more