# Compressed JS Decoder

Tags: javascript, decode, jscompress

http://www.lotterypost.com/js-compress.aspx

This is site is very nice for compressing JS

but I want to decode....

And instead of online is there any free best tool to encode/decode Js

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to unpack the contents of a javascript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460751/how-to-unpack-the-contents-of-a-javascript-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://jsbeautifier.org/ - Online Javascript unpacker and beautifier.