# How to "decode" some obfuscated JavaScript in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Here is one example:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('4.h={H:9(d){T 7.F(9(){g 1=7;1.3={8:4(d.8,7),i:4(d.i,7),m:4.z.J(7),5:d.5,t:d.t,j:d.j,K:d.K,b:d.b,A:d.A};4.h.s(1,0);4(S).v(\'W\',9(){1.3.m=4.z.J(1);4.h.s(1,0);4.h.E(1)});4.h.E(1);1.3.8.v(\'O\',9(){4(1.3.t,7).l(0).a.I=\'P\'}).v(\'R\',9(){4(1.3.t,7).l(0).a.I=\'11\'});4(Z).v(\'10\',9(e){g p=4.z.Y(e);g c=0;k(1.3.b&&1.3.b==\'L\')g r=p.x-1.3.m.x-(1.w-1.3.5*1.3.8.n())/2-1.3.5/2;u k(1.3.b&&1.3.b==\'N\')g r=p.x-1.3.m.x-1.w+1.3.5*1.3.8.n();u g r=p.x-1.3.m.x;g M=B.G(p.y-1.3.m.y-1.X/2,2);1.3.8.F(9(q){6=B.Q(B.G(r-q*1.3.5,2)+M);6-=1.3.5/2;6=6<0?0:6;6=6>1.3.j?1.3.j:6;6=1.3.j-6;C=1.3.A*6/1.3.j;7.a.D=1.3.5+C+\'f\';7.a.o=1.3.5*q+c+\'f\';c+=C});4.h.s(1,c)})})},s:9(1,c){k(1.3.b)k(1.3.b==\'L\')1.3.i.l(0).a.o=(1.w-1.3.5*1.3.8.n())/2-c/2+\'f\';u k(1.3.b==\'o\')1.3.i.l(0).a.o=-c/1.3.8.n()+\'f\';u k(1.3.b==\'N\')1.3.i.l(0).a.o=(1.w-1.3.5*1.3.8.n())-c/2+\'f\';1.3.i.l(0).a.D=1.3.5*1.3.8.n()+c+\'f\'},E:9(1){1.3.8.F(9(q){7.a.D=1.3.5+\'f\';7.a.o=1.3.5*q+\'f\'})}};4.V.U=4.h.H;',62,64,'|el||fisheyeCfg|jQuery|itemWidth|distance|this|items|function|style|halign|toAdd|options||px|var|iFisheye|container|proximity|if|get|pos|size|left|pointer|nr|posx|positionContainer|itemsText|else|bind|offsetWidth|||iUtil|maxWidth|Math|extraWidth|width|positionItems|each|pow|build|display|getPosition|valign|center|posy|right|mouseover|block|sqrt|mouseout|window|return|Fisheye|fn|resize|offsetHeight|getPointer|document|mousemove|none'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Obviously, this code is intentionally written to confuse other people. How can I understand it and rewrite it in simple code?

Is there some tool for this job? This is very common in HTML.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: You can try Dean Edward's decoder; this code has been encoded with his tool.

Answer (score 4):

This is not "encrypted", it is just obfuscated.

Yes, there are [tools available to help](http://www.kahusecurity.com/2011/javascript-deobfuscation-tools-part-1/), but it isn't a perfect process.  All of the original variable names and comments and what not are gone, so a tool can't really add that stuff back in.  You have to figure out the details yourself, but a tool can make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

I wish people would stop doing that. There's just no way to "encrypt" JavaScript. It's an exercise in futility (minification is good, but obfuscation is bad and useless)

That being said, try using [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). It gives me the following result:

```
jQuery.iFisheye = {
    build: function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var el = this;
            el.fisheyeCfg = {
                items: jQuery(options.items, this),
                container: jQuery(options.container, this),
                pos: jQuery.iUtil.getPosition(this),
                itemWidth: options.itemWidth,
                itemsText: options.itemsText,
                proximity: options.proximity,
                valign: options.valign,
                halign: options.halign,
                maxWidth: options.maxWidth
            };
            jQuery.iFisheye.positionContainer(el, 0);
            jQuery(window).bind('resize', function () {
                el.fisheyeCfg.pos = jQuery.iUtil.getPosition(el);
                jQuery.iFisheye.positionContainer(el, 0);
                jQuery.iFisheye.positionItems(el)
            });
            jQuery.iFisheye.positionItems(el);
            el.fisheyeCfg.items.bind('mouseover', function () {
                jQuery(el.fisheyeCfg.itemsText, this).get(0).style.display = 'block'
            }).bind('mouseout', function () {
                jQuery(el.fisheyeCfg.itemsText, this).get(0).style.display = 'none'
            });
            jQuery(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                var pointer = jQuery.iUtil.getPointer(e);
                var toAdd = 0;
                if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign && el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'center') var posx = pointer.x - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.x - (el.offsetWidth - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size()) / 2 - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth / 2;
                else if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign && el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'right') var posx = pointer.x - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.x - el.offsetWidth + el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size();
                else var posx = pointer.x - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.x;
                var posy = Math.pow(pointer.y - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.y - el.offsetHeight / 2, 2);
                el.fisheyeCfg.items.each(function (nr) {
                    distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(posx - nr * el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth, 2) + posy);
                    distance -= el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth / 2;
                    distance = distance < 0 ? 0 : distance;
                    distance = distance > el.fisheyeCfg.proximity ? el.fisheyeCfg.proximity : distance;
                    distance = el.fisheyeCfg.proximity - distance;
                    extraWidth = el.fisheyeCfg.maxWidth * distance / el.fisheyeCfg.proximity;
                    this.style.width = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth + extraWidth + 'px';
                    this.style.left = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * nr + toAdd + 'px';
                    toAdd += extraWidth
                });
                jQuery.iFisheye.positionContainer(el, toAdd)
            })
        })
    },
    positionContainer: function (el, toAdd) {
        if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign) if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'center') el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.left = (el.offsetWidth - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size()) / 2 - toAdd / 2 + 'px';
        else if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'left') el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.left = -toAdd / el.fisheyeCfg.items.size() + 'px';
        else if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'right') el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.left = (el.offsetWidth - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size()) - toAdd / 2 + 'px';
        el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.width = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size() + toAdd + 'px'
    },
    positionItems: function (el) {
        el.fisheyeCfg.items.each(function (nr) {
            this.style.width = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth + 'px';
            this.style.left = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * nr + 'px'
        })
    }
};
jQuery.fn.Fisheye = jQuery.iFisheye.build;
```

Other links (lifted from the very same page):

- Chrome: [jsbeautify-for-chrome](https://github.com/rixth/jsbeautify-for-chrome) by Tom Rix,
- Chrome: [Pretty Beautiful JavaScript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/piekbefgpgdecckjcpffhnacjflfoddg) by Will McSweeney,
- Firefox: [Javascript deminifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/) by Ben Murphy,
  to be used together with the firebug,
- Safari: [Safari extension](http://spadin.github.com/js-beautify-safari-extension) by Sandro Padin,
- Opera: [Readable JavaScript](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/readable-javascript/) by Dither,
- Opera: [Source](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/source/) extension by Deathamns,
- [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) proxy: JavaScript Formatter addon

Comment: Minification and obfuscation are fairly interchangeable for JS, don't you think?

Comment: @Brad Not really. Obfuscating code with the goal of preventing other people from stealing your code is dumb.

Comment: @quantumSoup, Agreed, I'm just saying that from DocWiki's perspective, getting the code back to something useful involves the same steps.

Answer (score 2):

Using one of the unpackers mentioned on this question:

- [How to unpack the contents of a Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460751/how-to-unpack-the-contents-of-a-javascript-file)

you can unpack the packed javascript to the following code:

```
jQuery.iFisheye = {
    build: function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var el = this;
            el.fisheyeCfg = {
                items: jQuery(options.items, this),
                container: jQuery(options.container, this),
                pos: jQuery.iUtil.getPosition(this),
                itemWidth: options.itemWidth,
                itemsText: options.itemsText,
                proximity: options.proximity,
                valign: options.valign,
                halign: options.halign,
                maxWidth: options.maxWidth
            };
            jQuery.iFisheye.positionContainer(el, 0);
            jQuery(window).bind('resize', function () {
                el.fisheyeCfg.pos = jQuery.iUtil.getPosition(el);
                jQuery.iFisheye.positionContainer(el, 0);
                jQuery.iFisheye.positionItems(el)
            });
            jQuery.iFisheye.positionItems(el);
            el.fisheyeCfg.items.bind('mouseover', function () {
                jQuery(el.fisheyeCfg.itemsText, this).get(0).style.display = 'block'
            }).bind('mouseout', function () {
                jQuery(el.fisheyeCfg.itemsText, this).get(0).style.display = 'none'
            });
            jQuery(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                var pointer = jQuery.iUtil.getPointer(e);
                var toAdd = 0;
                if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign && el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'center') var posx = pointer.x - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.x - (el.offsetWidth - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size()) / 2 - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth / 2;
                else if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign && el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'right') var posx = pointer.x - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.x - el.offsetWidth + el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size();
                else var posx = pointer.x - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.x;
                var posy = Math.pow(pointer.y - el.fisheyeCfg.pos.y - el.offsetHeight / 2, 2);
                el.fisheyeCfg.items.each(function (nr) {
                    distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(posx - nr * el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth, 2) + posy);
                    distance -= el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth / 2;
                    distance = distance < 0 ? 0 : distance;
                    distance = distance > el.fisheyeCfg.proximity ? el.fisheyeCfg.proximity : distance;
                    distance = el.fisheyeCfg.proximity - distance;
                    extraWidth = el.fisheyeCfg.maxWidth * distance / el.fisheyeCfg.proximity;
                    this.style.width = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth + extraWidth + 'px';
                    this.style.left = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * nr + toAdd + 'px';
                    toAdd += extraWidth
                });
                jQuery.iFisheye.positionContainer(el, toAdd)
            })
        })
    },
    positionContainer: function (el, toAdd) {
        if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign) if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'center') el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.left = (el.offsetWidth - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size()) / 2 - toAdd / 2 + 'px';
        else if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'left') el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.left = -toAdd / el.fisheyeCfg.items.size() + 'px';
        else if (el.fisheyeCfg.halign == 'right') el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.left = (el.offsetWidth - el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size()) - toAdd / 2 + 'px';
        el.fisheyeCfg.container.get(0).style.width = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * el.fisheyeCfg.items.size() + toAdd + 'px'
    },
    positionItems: function (el) {
        el.fisheyeCfg.items.each(function (nr) {
            this.style.width = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth + 'px';
            this.style.left = el.fisheyeCfg.itemWidth * nr + 'px'
        })
    }
};
jQuery.fn.Fisheye = jQuery.iFisheye.build;
```

Comment: Catch a man to iFisheye vs. teach a man to iFisheye... or something like that.  :-D  +1 for the link.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can get the original source here: http://interface.eyecon.ro/download. It's not really "obfuscated", in that the goal wasn't really obfuscation; rather, the goal was "compression" (minification), and the tool for that was a compressor/obfuscator.

(Of course, the tools that everyone else mentions are indispensable here. I used jsbeautifier.org to find that the whole thing is an assignment to `jQuery.iFisheye`, which then told me what to Google to find the above.)